# Format of pixel field in writableRaster

Tags: java, raster, pixel

In writableRaster class, there is a method:

```
public void setPixels(int x,
             int y,
             int w,
             int h,
             int[] iArray)
```

Where in iArray should store information about pixels
For a pixel: `233(r)244(g)10(b)`, how should it store in iArray?

Will it be `iArray[0] = 233`, `iArray[1] = 244`, `iArray[2] = 10`
or `iArray[0] = [24424410]` ?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, it should be `iArray[0] = 233, iArray[1] = 244, iArray[2] = 10` instead of `iArray[0] = [24424410]`.

However, the amount of data will depend on what the `WritableRaster` is backing. Consider the following example where we retrieve the `WriteableRaster` of two `BufferedImages`; one containing RGB data and the other ARGB data. If we retrieve pixel values, we can see that the array is of length 3 for RGB data and of length 4 for ARGB data.

**Code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BufferedImage rgbImage = new BufferedImage(8, 8,
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    WritableRaster rgbRaster = rgbImage.getRaster();

    BufferedImage argbImage = new BufferedImage(8, 8,
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    WritableRaster argbRaster = argbImage.getRaster();

    rgbImage.setRGB(0, 0, new Color(255, 125, 1, 16).getRGB());
    argbImage.setRGB(0, 0, new Color(255, 125, 1, 16).getRGB());

    int[] rgb = rgbRaster.getPixel(0, 0, (int[]) null);
    int[] argb = argbRaster.getPixel(0, 0, (int[]) null);
    System.out.print("rgb:");
    for (int i = 0; i < rgb.length; ++i)
        System.out.print(" "+rgb[i]);

    System.out.print("\nargb:");
    for (int i = 0; i < argb.length; ++i)
        System.out.print(" "+argb[i]);
}
```

**Output:**

```
rgb: 255 125 1
argb: 255 125 1 16
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I suppose the first 255 in output is for Alpha value? But why would the output of rgb be 255 125 1 rather than 125 1 16?